# Powershell: Find known string in xml file and move file when found

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to find a known string ('**Error while archiving**') in an XML file as I want to move the file when the string was found. Here is what I've got so far but I feel the content is not checked. The file always gets moved to the Output Directory 2 when I uncomment the **else** condition.

```
$FileDirectory="D:\Test\ImputFileDirectory";
$OutputPath="Z:\Test\OutpuDirectory";
$OutputPath2="Z:\Test\OutputDirectory2";

cls
Get-ChildItem $FileDirectory *.xml -recurse -File | ForEach-Object {
    $FilePath = $_.FullName
    $Content = Get-Content $FilePath -Raw

    if ($Content -match '[E081] Error while archiving' ) {
        Move-Item $FilePath $OutputPath
        }
#        else {
#        Move-Item $FilePath $OutputPath2
#    }

}
```

Here is the content of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<dump date="20230824" time="134800">
    <errormessage>
        <text>[E081] Error while archiving</text>
    </errormessage>
    <TimeStamp>2023-08-21 08:14:46</TimeStamp>
    <Type>System</Type>
    <Owner>administrator</Owner>
    <ProcessMessage>
        <TimeStamp>2023-08-24 13:46:59</TimeStamp>
        <Type>API</Type>
        <Action></Action>
        <sMessage>
            Document skipped. Data transfer aborted.
        </sMessage>
    </ProcessMessage>
</dump>
```

What do I miss?

Comment: -match parameter in Powershell means evaluate as regex. All the dots and question marks in your XML file are getting treated as special regex characters. What you need is the -like parameter

Comment: Unfortunately, the -like parameter doesn't work either. Is there a different way of archiving what I’m after?

Comment: Sorry I thought you match on the whole XML. I just ran the thing myself and the condition works for me: $a = Get-Content "C:\TEST\test.xml" -Raw;
$a -match 'Error while archiving' =>
True

Comment: you need to escape `[ ]` if you want to match `[E081] Error while archiving` literally: `-match '\[E081] Error while archiving'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if condition always faild due to the special charaters in the string **[**E081**]**. I had to use *-match [regex]::Escape('[E081] Error while archiving')* to get it to work.

```
$FileDirectory="D:\Test\ImputFileDirectory";
$OutputPath="Z:\Test\OutpuDirectory";
$OutputPath2="Z:\Test\OutputDirectory2";

cls
Get-ChildItem $FileDirectory *.xml -recurse -File | ForEach-Object {
    $FilePath = $_.FullName
    $Content = Get-Content $FilePath -Raw

    if ($Content -match [regex]::Escape('[E081] Error while archiving') ) {
        Move-Item $FilePath $OutputPath
        }
#        else {
#        Move-Item $FilePath $OutputPath2
#    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use \ as per below and mentioned by Santiago Squarzon in the comments.

```
if ($Content -match ('\[E081] Error while archiving'))
```

instead of `if ($Content -match [regex]::Escape('[E081] Error while archiving')`